# Outlook set sensitivity level for single email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

How to set Sensitivity level for an individual email.

Comment: Never heard of that setting.  Are you sure you mean to use the word *sensitivity*?

Comment: For email recipients, to treat the email as:

- For Private - Please treat this as Private.
- For Personal - Please treat this as Personal.
- For Confidential - Please treat this as Confidential.

For e.g. - Emails are sometimes mandated to be flagged Confidential in-case they contain any sensitive data.

Comment: Please [edit] your response into your question. Also, indicate the version of Outlook you're using.

Comment: OP appears to have submitted this question in order to answer it himself. It's brief, but it is precise and the question is as simple as he has made it. I do not believe it ought to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This image reference shares a way to do it [image]

Reference:

- [Ref-1](http://en.officetutor365.com/changing-the-level-of-sensitivity-or-importance-for-email-messages-on-outlook-2010/)
- [Ref-2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mark-an-email-message-as-important-private-or-sensitive-f480dcea-59a9-48da-b7ed-3b3e0ab27a62?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=4)